# not able to connect to 9300 port through telnet elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a elasticsearch node running on a server. My application which is on different server trying to connect to elasticsearch on 9300 through TransportClient. But I am getting following error "Caused by: org.elasticsearch.client.transport.NoNodeAvailableException: None of the configured nodes are available: [{#transport#-1}{Ir-wPDBRR9umDbtoqGIp0A}{X.X.X.X}{X.X.X.X:9300}]".

And I am not able to connect to the elasticsearch server on 9300 port through telnet as well. Here are my elasticsearch.yml settings

```
transport.host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
network.host: 0.0.0.0
```

is there any setting I am missing to access the ES remotely?
Any help will be appriciated.

Comment: Check the ES logs, sounds like the service is not ready. Also, why are you connecting to the Transport Client, I think this will be removed in the future. Try the HTTP (9200) port instead.

Comment: Is that your complete configuration? I wouldn't set the network host to a wildcard, also you might want to add "discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts" to your configuration.

Comment: These properties worked for me. transport.host: localhost
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
network.host: X.X.X.X
transport.publish_host: X.X.X.X
transport.bind_host: X.X.X.X
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: